# How do I get sum of all figures inside a string but for the whole column?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Data:

- MEL1INFA73 Confirmed. Ksh29.00 sent to Safaricom Offers  for account Tunukiwa on 21/5/18 at 3:29 AM New M-PESA balance is Ksh5.50. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00.
- MEE6ESSVCS Confirmed. Ksh2,240.00 paid to Naivas West End Plaza. on 14/5/18 at 8:13 PM.New M-PESA balance is Ksh4,753.50. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00.
- MEF1EZ0MNR Confirmed.You have received Ksh10,000.00 from Barclays Bank K LTD 303031 on 15/5/18 at 9:36 AM New M-PESA balance is Ksh14,775.50.  Buy goods with M-PESA.

The following code generates sum of figures in each row other than the whole column:

```
 <?php 
                if(count($json_data["data"]) > 0){ ?>
                    <?php $_count = 1;
                        foreach($json_data["data"] as $row){ ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php 
                                $str =$row["msg_body"];
                                preg_match_all("/ksh\s*(\d+\.\d+)/i", $str, $matches);
                                echo array_sum($matches[1]); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php $_count ++; }
                    ?>
            <?php }else{

                }
            ?></td>
```

Comment: Have you thought of having a running total of the results of `array_sum($matches[1])`?

Comment: how is that done please?

Comment: Do you want the total results of figures for all three messages?

Comment: yes, messages are stored in different rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just need to store the whole sum and then print it out somewhere. Something like:

```php
<?php 
                if(count($json_data["data"]) > 0){ ?>
                    <?php $_count = 1;
                          $totalSum = 0;
                        foreach($json_data["data"] as $row) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php 
                                $str =$row["msg_body"];
                                preg_match_all("/ksh\s*(\d+\.\d+)/i", $str, $matches);
                                $rowSum = array_sum($matches[1]);
                                $totalSum += $rowSum;
                                echo  $rowSum;?></td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php $_count ++; }
                    ?>
                    <tr><td>Total sum: <?php echo $totalSum; ?></td></tr>
            <?php }else{

                }
            ?></td>
```

You can adjust your html, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Because we are dealing with an array and preg_match_all, then I believe you could implode the array and do one preg_match_all instead of looping it.

```
$AllItems = implode(" ", $json_data["data"]);
preg_match_all("/ksh\s*(\d+\.\d+)/i", str_replace(",","",$AllItems), $matches);
$total = array_sum($matches[1]);
```

Example:
https://3v4l.org/Pk7YT

Edit noticed there was commas as thousands separators. That needs to be removed for the regex and summing to work with str_replace.